# iScroll4 and Bootstrap's scrollspy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iscroll4

I've been trying to get [Bootstrap's scrollspy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) to work with a scrolling div that uses [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Scrollspy and iScroll4 both seem to have the same functionality.  So I'm a little puzzled as to what you are asking for and why you would use both on the same screen.

Comment: I assume scrollspy is listening for the window.onScroll event, but because you are using iscroll, that event isn't fired. You might want to recreate the functionality of scrollspy while listening to iscrolls events: http://iscrolljs.com/#custom-events